# Advance grep in centos 7

Tags: linux, grep

Here iam trying to see how many different string attach to a string like
in my file, theres ip=192.168.1.1, ip=192.168.10.1, ip=192.168.20.1. i would like to know how many different ips are there in ip.

Comment: You want to know how many IP addresses are in the file?

Comment: yes correct iam using grep to do it. cat /var/log/secure | grep -cH "\(ip\)" giving the total

Comment: i did use cat /var/log/secure | grep -o -E "(rhost=*)" | sort | uniq -c
but this is not what i want.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. The code you put in comments should be in your original Q. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: correct, but that was the output that i was looking for. anyway, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Cyrus. i have added `| sort | uniq -c`

```
grep -oE '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
10 192.168.1.1
50 192.168.10.1
232 192.168.20.1
```